# SQL Timeout is longer than I set it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, timeout, sqlconnection

I use SqlConnection in C# and I open the connection with `sqlconnection.Open()` to a VM were MSSQL runs on it. If the credentials are correct, the connection is available below a second. But if e.g. the DB is not available, it causes a long Timeout about 45 seconds.

That is why I added to the Connection string `Connection Timeout={Timeout}`, this gets assigned because `sqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` is equal the Timeout I set.

I set the Timeout to 5 sec and tried to connect to a not existing Database. Unfortunately, the Timeout was longer than I expected.

> 20/06/2018 08:04:39: Open Connection
>
> 20/06/2018 08:05:11: Connection failed

My goal would be to break up the connection after ca. 10 sec.

**TL;DR;** Can I affect the Timeout? And if this is not possible,
why is the Timeout about 32 sec. even though I set the Timeout to 5 sec.

**EDIT:**

```
connectionstring = $@"Server={Ip};Database={DbName};User Id={Username};Password={Password};Connection Timeout={Timeout}";
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{ 
    try {
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "Open Connection");
        sqlConnection.Open();
    }
    catch
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "Connection failed");
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I add `ConnectRetryCount=0;ConnectRetryInterval=1;` to the Connection string, it didn't made any change.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: See following posting : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8c87fb8-2ef2-429f-af52-20e9e0074357/changing-default-connection-timeout-value-for-sql-connection?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50944424/5507322 - Fair point, but it does not work in all scenarios.

An explanation of this above, why it is not reliable and the solution to my problem:
http://improve.dk/controlling-sqlconnection-timeouts/